# Jquery .animate not working on first click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Cant seem to get this working on the first click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var expand = $('.expand-icon');

  $(expand).on('click', function() {
    $(this).children('i').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
    $(this).closest("li").find(".submenu").eq(0).toggleClass('active')
      .animate({
        height: 'toggle'
      });
  });
});
```

link to demo https://codepen.io/MistaNeilo/pen/mBvdrp

Comment: It's expanding but then immediately closing.

Comment: `.toggleClass('active')` displays the menu, then `animate` undoes that by setting its height to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var expand = $('.expand-icon');

 $(expand).on('click', function() {
   $(this).children('i').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
    $(this).closest("li").find(".submenu").eq(0).slideToggle('300', 
   function() 
   {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
 });

 });
 });
```